# Overview look of header inclusions

Tags: c++

When a project grows it becomes hard to get an overview of header inclusion. I've noticed our object files have grown rather large and so I'm thinking there's a lot to be won by rearranging dependencies. This is where the problem begin, I know of no convenient way to actually get an overview on what headers actually get included for a specific source file. There's the possibility of outputting the pre-processed source files, that however creates huge files with loads of irrelevant information. I'm thinking there must be a tool for this, but I can't seem to find any. I'm on windows, so in case anyone know of a good tool / way to actually do this for windows I'd be eternally grateful.

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio, I think there's an option to make it tell you whenever it's including a file. The output window will then tell you during compilation.

Comment: Lots of dupes, including http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793369/graph-of-included-files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual C++ has the [`/showIncludes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdkef6tk%28VS.80%29.aspx) switch, which causes the compiler to output a message when an include is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a tool, but lays out some basic principles for good design of header file #includes:

http://www.eventhelix.com/realtimemantra/headerfileincludepatterns.htm

Answer (score 0):

doxygen makes nice #include file dependency graphs too, if you want to see how all your headers fit together.